# HBM file class definition where clause not getting appended when joining with other entity

Tags: join, append, where-clause, entity, hbm

we have a hbm file with class definition as

.

Now when the entity is getting called in query the where clause in class definition in hbm gets appended automatically. But when we join the entity with some other entity then the where clause on class definition in hbm is not getting appended. Why is so? If this is as expected then what should be done to overcome this?

Just to share the context as I already got the answer to the above:--

When working with Hibernate and HBM (Hibernate Mapping) files, it’s essential to understand how the where clause behaves in different scenarios. Let’s break down the issue you’re facing:

Automatic Appending of where Clause:

In your HBM file, you’ve defined a where clause for the ABC entity: .
When you query the ABC entity directly, Hibernate automatically appends the specified where clause to the SQL query. This behavior is expected and ensures that only non-deleted records are retrieved.
Joining with Other Entities:

However, when you join the ABC entity with another entity (e.g., using an INNER JOIN or LEFT JOIN), Hibernate does not automatically include the where clause from the HBM file.
The reason behind this behavior is that the where clause is specific to the primary entity (ABC) and does not apply to the joined entities.
Join conditions are separate from the where clause and are typically specified in the query itself.
Overcoming the Issue:

To overcome this, you have a few options:
Explicitly Include the Condition in the Query:
When joining entities, explicitly include the condition related to is_deleted=0 in your query. For example:
SQL

SELECT ...
FROM ABC rav
INNER JOIN OtherEntity oe ON rav.someColumn = oe.someColumn
WHERE rav.is_deleted = 0

Use Dynamic Mapping:
If you need more flexibility, consider using dynamic mapping capabilities provided by Hibernate. Annotations like @Where and @Filter allow you to dynamically modify the SQL conditions based on runtime parameters or context 1.
For instance, you can annotate your entity class with @Where(clause = "is_deleted=0") to apply the condition globally to all queries involving that entity.
Keep in mind that these annotations are specific to Hibernate and may not be directly portable to other JPA implementations.
Customize Your Query Logic:
Depending on your use case, you might need to customize the query logic further. You can build complex queries using LINQ-like expressions or dynamic predicates.
For example, in Entity Framework (C#), you can construct dynamic where clauses based on user selections or other criteria 2.
Remember that the behavior you’re observing is by design, and the where clause in the HBM file is primarily associated with the individual entity. When joining entities, you’ll need to handle additional conditions explicitly in your queries or leverage dynamic mapping features.

Might be hibernate had resolved the above issue in annotations only not sure as I did not find any reference to this.

Has hibernate had resolved the above issue in annotations only but not the hbm way?